# Telerik Silverlight RadPanelBar Hierarchical Data Template

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-4.0, telerik, radpanelbar

I need to display the following layout with a telerik PanelBar.

[image: RadPanelBar template]

With the code below I was able to achieve everything except the **92%** stuff in each panel.

XAML:

```
<UserControl.Resources>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="PanelBarItemTemplate">
        <Grid x:Name="grdCategory" ShowGridLines="True">
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="30"></RowDefinition>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="60*"></ColumnDefinition>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="40*"></ColumnDefinition>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Grid x:Name="grdSubCategory" Grid.Column="0" Style="{StaticResource CategoryLeftStyle}" >
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="20"></RowDefinition>
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="50*"></ColumnDefinition>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="25*"></ColumnDefinition>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="25*"></ColumnDefinition>
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding CategoryTitle}" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0"/>
                <HyperlinkButton Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" Style="{StaticResource DetailLinkStyle}" Content="Details" Click="Home_Click"></HyperlinkButton>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Score}" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="2"/>
            </Grid>
            <TextBlock Text="92%" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0" Grid.RowSpan="2" FontSize="32" FontWeight="Bold"/>
        </Grid>
    </DataTemplate>

    <telerik:HierarchicalDataTemplate x:Key="PanelBarHeaderTemplate"
                                ItemsSource="{Binding SubReports}"
                                ItemTemplate="{StaticResource PanelBarItemTemplate}">
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding CategoryTitle}" />
    </telerik:HierarchicalDataTemplate>

</UserControl.Resources>

<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot">
    <telerik:RadPanelBar x:Name="radPanelBar" 
                            ItemTemplate="{StaticResource PanelBarHeaderTemplate}"
                            IsSingleExpandPath="False" >
    </telerik:RadPanelBar>
</Grid>
```

in the xaml.cs file I provided the ItemsSource.

Can somebody help me out?

Comment: I don't think the RadPanelBar can do what you want 'out of the box'. You may have better luck asking this question on the Telerik forums at http://www.telerik.com/community/forums.aspx.  There you might be able to get the help of the people who actually wrote the Telerik controls.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All that code works perfectly well for the individual items, but to place the 92% relative to those items (somewhat outside of the sub-items) you would need to also modify the ItemContainerStyle of RadPanelBar.  Easiest way is to extract it in Blend, then look for the section under PanelBarItemTopLevelTemplate named ItemsContainer.  This is a somewhat crude version, but I made a public property on my item called CalcInt that calculates the sum of a property on the SubReport items so it can be bound from the base item level.  My modified code looks like so:

```
                <Grid x:Name="ItemsContainer" Grid.Row="1" Visibility="Collapsed">
                <telerik:LayoutTransformControl x:Name="transformationRoot">
                    <Grid>
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition />
                            <ColumnDefinition />
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ItemsPresenter/>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding CalcInt}" FontSize="48" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
                    </Grid>                     
                </telerik:LayoutTransformControl>
            </Grid>
```

I basically changed it from just containing an ItemsPresenter to a grid with some layout to display my extra-large TextBlock.

If you need a sample of the code or have any other questions feel free to hit me up on Twitter - @EvanHutnick.

Cheers!

-Evan

Answer (score 0):

Hi I think you need to define a converter : IValueConverter and bind to the Label so you can calculate the percentual.
Mario